# Serialization Error using Elasticsearch Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to have my collection of indexed documents searchable using console input, I get a Serialization error and I don't understand why or how to fix it. I get that it's an error of the type of my variable, but I'm not sure if its giving the wrong type or wants a different type.

```
searchstr = input("Search for a character \n")

body = {"query": {"prefix" : { "name": { searchstr } } } }

print(es.search(index="sw", doc_type="people", body=body))
```

Here's the error; `elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'query': {'prefix': {'name': {'Lu'}}}}, TypeError("Unable to serialize {'Lu'} (type: <class 'set'>)",))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right way to put prefix query

```
searchstr = input("Search for a character \n")

body = {"query": {"prefix" : { "value":  searchstr  } } }

print(es.search(index="sw", doc_type="people", body=body))
```